# Include header file if it exists to redefine macros in C

Tags: c, makefile, header, preprocessor

I have two header files, one that is a library with a number of default macros defined
i.e:

libraryheader.h:

```
#define ANAME 1
#define BNAME 2
.
.
.
```

and I want to be able to have another optional header that the user can supply to redefine these macros in the project

optional.h:

```
#define ANAME 5
#define BNAME 15
.
.
.
```

The header optional.h doesn't always exist and I only want to include it if it does exist. Is there a way in the makefile or library header to check if this header exists and redefine the macros.

I'm thinking to check if the file exists in the makefile and set a flag by putting the following in the makefile

```
ifdef $(test -f optional.h && echo "present")
```

and then somehow check the flag macro in the library header. 
But I haven't had any success yet. Thank you

Comment: Well, you could have your makefile update the compile flags to define `HAS_OPTIONAL_H` macro, and then you can wrap your `#include` line in a `#ifdef`.

Comment: `myprog:CPPFLAGS += $(if $(wildcard optional.h),-include optional.h)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Matt mentioned in comment "wildcard" can be used.

However, when I tested it using a small program I had to do the following things.

If I include the "optional.h" in my .c file always, then it will give build error when the .h file is not present. Similarly, if I dont include, even if the file is present I will not be able to update the macros. So I did the following in my makefile.

```
CFLAGS += $(if $(wildcard ./optional.h),-include ./optional.h -DINCLUDE_OPTIONAL_H)
```

In my .c file I used INCLUDE_OPTIONAL_H for including the optional.h as below.

```
#ifdef INCLUDE_OPTIONAL_H
#include "optional.h"
#endif
```

In optional.h, I checked if a macro is already defined and undefined it and then updated it.

```
#ifdef ANAME
#undef ANAME
#endif
#define ANAME <new_value>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't checking the INCLUDE_OPTIONAL_H flag in the right spot.